# SSD performance parameters - latency vs IOPS?

Tags: performance, latency, solid-state-drive

The most used performance metrics for SSDs are said to be: Throughput (MBps), IOPS and latency (ms). I'm a bit confused from the latter 2, since:

- IOPS - measures how many input output operations are completed every
  second
- latency - how long it takes for an IO operation to be completed from
  beginning to end

(taking the definitions from here: https://www.custompcreview.com/articles/iops-throuhput-latency-understanding-ssd-hdd-storage-performance-benchmarks/)
So if latency defines the duration of processing of I/O operation, I would naively conclude that IOPS = 1/latency (at least for depth queue = 1). But that's clearly not the case. So what's the difference here?
I understand that SSDs benefit from large queue depths (number of concurrent I/O operations), but even if these operations are concurent, the total number of I/O operations per second would be inversely proportional to I/O latency, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll quote from here, because the article answers what you need:
https://storageswiss.com/2013/12/10/what-is-latency-and-how-is-it-different-from-iops/

> In order to maintain IOPS performance storage systems need  enough
>   pending requests for data be available (in a queue) so that the
>   latencies of a few individual requests don’t adversely impact the
>   overall IOPS performance of the system. When queue depths are low,
>   latency becomes a larger determinant of storage performance and in
>   flash based storage systems, low (or no) queue depth is a common
>   occurrence.
>
> While adequate transaction queues are required to realize SSD
>   performance, large queue depths can actually mask latency in the short
>   run. Essentially, the system can process a large number of
>   transactions per second from the queue (high IOPS) but still take a
>   relatively long time to complete those transactions (long latency).
>   So, in the short-term IOPS may look good, even though the system’s
>   ability to improve performance in the long-term is poor. For these
>   reasons, latency is often a more important metric than IOPS for
>   measuring SSD system performance.

Summary: Latency affects IOPS, but not in a consistent manner. Hence it's considered as another measurement for SSDs, next to IOPS.